# Most optimal way to write a function

Tags: c#, string

SQL code that connects to different databases 
**say dbs= a,b,c** 

Also a big SQL query whose name should be prefixed by database name. So its essentially a string operations on the big query to replace all the above mentioned database names. Whats the most optimal way of writing this in C#

Comment: How about you post what you've come up with so far?

Comment: Agreed with Mike Robinson.  'plzshowustehcodez', as it were.

Comment: "Most optimal" is like "most best". "Optimal" implies most already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your question is very clear but I think you are looking for this:

Use the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class for all string operations that include more than 3 strings.

Comment: I used something much simpler. String.Format() and it works like a charm!